# Why is "Whataboutism" often criticized?

Tags: rhetoric

**Whataboutism** or **Whataboutary** is the technique or practice of responding to an accusation or difficult question by making a counter-accusation or raising a different issue.

Examples:

The USA to Russia: "*You invaded Ukraine and killed tens of thousands of people.*"
Russia to the USA: "*What about Vietnam, Iraq, Afghanistan,...?*"

---

Now, my question is, why is "Whataboutism" often criticized?

Those who criticize whataboutism, What better type of reply do they suggest?

Comment: "Whataboutism" is formally known as the fallacy of [tu quoque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque) (Latin for "you too").

Comment: Related: [How can I respond to Whataboutism?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/how-can-i-respond-to-whataboutism)

Comment: Why're you picking on whataboutism? What about all the OTHER logical fallacies?

Comment: @dan04 Whataboutism is broader than tu quoque, as it encompasses bringing up things that the accuser didn't do, e.g. "Why are you complaining about Ukraine? Isn't the war in Ethiopia even worse?"

Comment: @Acccumulation That's typically what the word should mean. Bringing up unrelated things. But I find when people say it is usually to dismiss a challenge that *is* related.

Comment: @Acccumulation bringing up (more specifically: implying) things that the accuser didn't do sounds more like a "loaded question".

Comment: @hennin No. "Loaded question" has a specific meaning: it's a question that implicitly makes an assertion (this assertion not having a valid basis is also generally understood to be part of the meaning). The classic example is "Have you stopped beating your wife?", which implicitly asserts that you have previously beaten your wife. I suppose there can be overlap. For instance, in my example of "Why are you complaining about Ukraine? Isn't the war in Ethiopia even worse?", this could be worded in a way that implicitly asserts that the other person doesn't care about Ethiopia.

Comment: Most, if not all, of the discussion here is about when the person being addressed tries to deflect by bringing up something the person addressing them did.  This is a common form and the one represented by the example in the question but this isn't the only way whataboutery is used.  For instance "We are need to do something about people blocking the road and footpath outside schools when they are dropping off or collecting their children".  "What about all the murders in the city? Should you not fix that before you worry about where people park their cars for a few minutes?"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

### Why is "Whataboutism" often criticized?

"Whataboutism" is criticized because this is a way **to escape an** issue rather than **to discuss an issue**, and that's why that most of conversations start at a point but they would never end where they've been started, when someone uses this technique it means **they have no justification for their acts or false claims** and by bringing up a weakness or controversial issue mostly pertaining the second party of the discussion they try to hide their own weekness at responding. (Please note that I'm talking about general situations not particularly Russia and America or the war in Ukraine)

This would be a successful attempt to escape if you know what to bring up, if you can bring up a very sensitive issue that the second party can't leave alone you have changed the course of discussion but it necessarily doesn't mean that you have won the discussion, when you bring up something sensitive about the one who is criticizing you, you can actually make the conversation to backfire cause the second party would try to acquit themselves from the alleged charges so your wrongdoing is forgotten.

This is criticized cause it never answers the question in the minds of the audiences, like your example, the US says "Your crimes in Ukraine" and Russia says "what about your crimes in Iraq, Vietnam and....", Russia is actually pointing out an important issue because horrific things happened in Iraq, Vietnam and other places, but the question is not answered and the issue is just screwed.

So if Russia is really doing those alleged crimes, the point that the US has attacked many countries itself and killed many people doesn't justify the crimes of Russia and if Russia isn't really doing those crimes so why don't they bring up an evidence and prove the falsehood of the words of the US? The fact that the US attacked Iraq for the phony pretext of WMDs doesn't give any permission to Russia to do the same.

But there's still a point that should not be overlooked and that is **can a criminal be a witness**? If a drug dealer that is arrested can't be a witness for the crimes of his gang so who can be? (Again i'm saying that I'm discussing in general not specifically about Russia and the US), the fact that the guy himself was a drugdealer doesn't make his words about his gang useless that if it did, why the detectives interrogate the person to make him rat on his gang?

So we can't really say that if the person X is a criminal, that person can't accuse the person Y of a crime. But still this is the pot calls the kettle black. If the US killed people in Iraq it doesn't mean that they can't condemn Russia for killing people in Ukraine. (this is just an example, I don't claim Russia is really killing or not), but of course if you think someone is doing a wrong thing, you shouldn't do it yourself, that if you do, then you're a hypocritical guy.

This is actually true about both parts, if Russia condemns the US so why itself attacked Ukraine? And if the US condemns Russia why itself has attacked many countries? And that's why the pot calls the kettle black, but again it doesn't mean that the pot or kettle aren't black!

As user366312 says, "A criminal can be a witness, but a criminal can't be a judge." the fact that the US can criticize Russia doesn't mean that the US has any right to punish Russia too, as I mentioned in the comments, you can't wipe off a dirty window with a dirty cloth, if we want to punish, we have to have an impartial third party that punishes both sides cause both of the drugdealer and his accomplice have committed crime.

### Those who criticize whataboutism, What better type of reply do they suggest?

As I mentioned above, the best answer on behalf of the party which is being accused is to bring up evidence to prove the falsehood of the charges, or else by screwing the word they only leave an unanswered question in the minds of the audiences which would cause distrust.

This is like whe Russia says I have attacked Ukraine cause they were neo-Nazi, I( supposedly) come up and say, so what about the crimes of the Soviet Union? This is pretty absurd, the right thing is to ask Russia if you claim that they are Nazis, can you bring an evidence to support that?

Comment: A criminal can be a witness alright, but a criminal can't be a judge.

Comment: "Discuss an issue" is disingenuous here, you are talking about a deflection of "discussing and condemning your behavior". You don't get to discuss other parties' behavior without answering the *who are you to lecture me?* question. Or at least there would be no dialogue on those terms.

Comment: Just a side note: To ask people to prove a negative is often times much more difficult and switches the burden of proof from the accuser to the accused so "why don't you simply proof me wrong" is not technically a fallacy but practically a rhetorical slight of hand that is in the grey area. Except for when you've actually produced evidence of the killing and the other party just dismisses them without evidence, then it would be the other side deflecting the burden of proof. Again the burder of proof is less about being falacious and more about be a good faith actor.

Comment: This answer is very difficult to parse. I'm surprised it has the selection. Abandoned by a deleted user, so whatever.

Comment: In the USA, can a judge be convicted for DUI and then judge other people doing the same?

Answer (score 98):

It's a logical fallacy. It notably doesn't argue that the act was justified, at most it only argues that you and I are both in the same boat - so if you are wrong, I am wrong too.

Concretely:

> The USA to Russia: "You invaded Ukraine and killed tens of thousands of people."
>
> Russia to the USA: "What about Vietnam, Iraq, Afghanistan,...?"

Say Russia is right that the Vietnam War, the Iraq War, and the Afghanistan War are unjust (implied by the original claim "You invaded Ukraine and killed tens of thousands of people"). Then Russia's argument only shows that the US is just as unjust as Russia is.

The USA could reasonably say "OK, so I'm a hypocrite and I invaded Vietnam, Iraq, Afghanistan, and killed tens of thousands of people. And you still invaded Ukraine and killed tens of thousands of people." The original claim - that it was unjust to invade Ukraine and kill tens of thousands of people - is not refuted.

The kind of response that is needed is an argument that shows why it was just to invade Ukraine.

Comment: This is somewhat of a straw man because whataboutism is not the one justification for Russian invasion, or even the main one.

Comment: @alamar but it's the example given by the OP.

Comment: Usually it is used in the fashion `- Your justification for invading X is laughable! - What about your invasion to Y with even less sound justification?` - at this point a moral deadlock occurs.

Comment: It depends on the original claim the "whataboutism" addresses. If the claim was *"you are the worst, you did some unspeakable evil no one ever did"*, or just *"you are worse than us"* then whataboutism can be a right and justified answer. However, if the original claim is merely a criticism, then using whataboutism as an answer can be justly criticized  as trying to deflect the blame, as someone else doing bad thing doesn't mean the accused party is innocent.

Comment: As a logical argument it is indeed a fallacy. As a moral argument it is more successful. Moral relativism is a thing.

Comment: Whataboutism is only fallacious if the implied argument is "I did nothing wrong because you did the same thing." But I don't think people use whataboutism to dispute the truth of the claim. Rather, I think the implied argument is "you have no moral authority to criticize me because you are also guilty" or "if you want to do something about my actions, then we should also do something about your actions" which I think is valid depending on the context. Of course, if you leave the actual argument implicit, then whataboutism is mostly just a distraction, and not a productive statement

Comment: Or Russia is arguing that all those wars are fine...

Comment: @THummus the argument "you have no moral authority to criticize me because you are also guilty" is not valid to me because it presumes that target the argument is deflected toward is still supporting their original action: maybe it did something and now knows it's bad so there is an implied presumption in it. But even if it wasn't the case, it doesn't diminish the original point which is the focus of the discussion. Attempting to deflect a discussion means there are no valid arguments to support a point.

Comment: @Thomas Sorry, by "valid" I meant logically valid. I agree that deflecting a discussion is a poor debating technique, and doesn't diminish the original point. It's just not a fallacy of logic.

Comment: Just a note on Vietnam: the US committed many horrendous acts, massive amounts of people died and lots of property was destroyed, the war was deeply unpopular as it dragged on in the US, etc… but it wasn’t “unjustified”. The US involvement in Vietnam had one simple justification: aiding South Vietnam and preventing it being taken over by North Vietnam, a communist country. The US committed itself to fight communism all throughout the Cold War; that was the justification.

Comment: @MDevelopment That justification hinges on the notion that South Vietnam wasn't a marionette state set up by the colonial powers to defend their interests after they were forced to leave. Notion which was not exactly universally accepted at the time, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @MDevelopment The US was aiding a country whose leadership was chosen though a wildly fraudulent referendum (won by 98.9%) where the losing side was at one point legally barred from campaigning. (That kind of situation might sound familiar, come to think of it.) The U.S. clearly did not care too much exactly _what_ it was defending from communism. (Not that the Democratic Republic of Vietnam was any better, mind you.)

Comment: By saying "What about Vietnam, Iraq, Afghanistan?" I would imply that the US does not consider that invading other countries is wrong. Therefore the reason the US is defending Ukraine is different and by defending Ukraine the US actually defends the interests of the US. And if you do not think that invading other countries is wrong and do it yourself than what right do you have to criticize me for the same?

Comment: @CITBL "you do not have the right to criticize me" is a different statement from "the Ukraine war is unjust". Both statements can be true at the same time. Therefore, responding with "you do not have the right to criticize me" still does not refute the claim.

Comment: @Allure But their intention is no to refute the claim. Their intention is for you to shut up. For example: how can a thieve accuse others of thievery and go around telling people how thievery is wrong?? It's such a contradiction...

Comment: As @THummus implies, many instances of claimed whataboutism are about changing the discussion to fair treatment, before the actual complaints are addressed. "If what I'm doing is X, then why is this other thing not X? If it is also X, then you need a different frame for your complaint that demonstrates your willingness to argue fairly."

Comment: @CITBL 'Whataboutism' is actually the foundation of law. Its called (legal) [precedent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precedent) or more technically [stare decisis](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/stare_decisis)

Answer (score 82):

Whataboutism isn’t a reply, Whataboutism is a **deflection** of an accusation.

It is not an attempt to address a concern, but instead an attempt to **change the subject**.

As politics is getting people to agree with you, it is as valid as anything else politicians do, but is frequently less effective than simply attacking the opposition directly.  Those that agree with you will appreciate the attack, those that don’t may be moved by it.  Whataboutism rarely persuades people as it is recognized as a deflection, and unless the Whatabout is significantly worse than what is being deflected, that makes the Whataboutism seem guilty.

Sometimes the “what about” is a totally different subject, which makes the changing of the subject rather obvious, but doesn’t really change much else.

Politically it’s chancy.

Comment: It should also be noted that it's a way of equating things without considering context. For instance, if someone shoves you to bully you and retorts that you shoved someone else, but you did it to help them avoid being hit by a vehicle. It's a red herring making a false equivalence, and an easy way to call anyone hypocritical.

Comment: @Tanath Ah, I see. So in the original example, the US was invading Vietnam, Iraq, Afghanistan etc in order to help them.

Comment: There's a couple false assumptions in your comment.

Comment: "Russia invaded Ukraine and killed thousands of innocent people". "But what about Hunter Biden's laptop?"

Answer (score 32):

To put it simply, just because someone else does something bad doesn't mean you(or someone else) can do something bad.

If you break the rules it doesn't matter that someone else in the past has broken the rules. Or if you commit a crime it doesn't matter that others have also committed that same or other crimes.

Comment: Most motorists speed or drink-drive or use their phone; that doesn't mean laws against those things aren't real.

Comment: Or, as Mom often said, two wrongs don't make a right.

Comment: @JoeW I deleted my comments because their content and intent were misunderstood.

Comment: @JoeW It might actually mean that. The better comparison would be that just because many people do bad stuff doesn't mean it's still bad.

Comment: If it's not about fair treatment, then it's actually an argument that neither the original complaint nor the whatabout are morally wrong. Ergo, "two wrongs don't make a right" doesn't properly retort a valid whatabout.

Answer (score 25):

'Whataboutism' isn't a fallacy (neither formal nor informal). 'Whataboutism' is a collective ego defense: a way of justifying, excusing, or obviating improper or immoral behavior by someone one side identifies with, through a superficial reference to ostensibly improper or immoral behavior by someone the other side identifies with.

'Whataboutism' isn't wrong as much as it's degenerative. A critique or condemnation generally carries a moral imperative of the sort:

> What X did is not something that is acceptable at any time or
> place, by any person.

'Whataboutism' inverts that to produce an amoral imperative such as:

> Someone on *your* side have done things akin to what X did, so you have no
> standing to criticize X for doing it.

'Whataboutism' produces a race to the bottom, where (potentially) every act, no matter how heinous, is defended to preserve the prestige of the group as a whole (or often merely to lower the prestige of some other group, so that one's own group seems prestigious by comparison). It's a sign that people have given up the idea of being good or virtuous in its own right, and instead put all their efforts into appearing marginally better than others.

Comment: It doesn't have to produce a race to the bottom.  In fact, the accusation of "whataboutism" has become a common way to get out of being accused of a hypocrisy.  Sometimes it's a false equivalence and sometimes it's a correct equivalence, but both correct and false equivalences are "whataboutisms."

Comment: Perhaps less race-to-the-bottom, and more "moral free-fall." If all parties refuse to acknowledge criticism from anyone who is not absolutely faultless, it is inevitable that all long-lived parties will become disqualified from attempting to persuade bad actors to reform. The resultant state is one in which everyone is permitted to do anything that does not trouble their own conscience, which is clearly intolerable. Imagine if the only laws that could be enforced were the ones _nobody_ had broken yet.

Comment: @wrod: Whether it's a false or correct equivalence, it still serves to disrupt or corrupt moral reasoning. That's the race to the bottom (or moral free-fall, as Tom would have it). The point is that 'whataboutism' in no way serves to encourage moral behavior, but instead justifies amoral/immoral behavior by diffusing blame.

Comment: @TedWrigley that's incorrect.  objecting to whatabouttism is immoral, and highly unethical, in itself (always).  which is why the OP uses it.  It's a trap.  He gets to getaway with defending something immoral by trying to solicit immoral objections.

Comment: "'Whataboutism' produces a race to the bottom" <- Not necessarily. If one canot get away with deflecting a "what about" claim, whataboutism could be considered to result in a "race to the top", in the sense of "we must all better our ways" and "we must all reflect upon our own actions through the parallel of deplorable actions by others".

Answer (score 15):

**"What better type of reply do they suggest?"**

The main question has, I feel, been well-answered, but the sub-question here has not been sufficiently addressed.

I can at least offer one suggestion towards it: Whataboutism can become *somewhat* valid if it is rephrased to point to precedent-setting incidents.

**Example 1**

An example would be if a US Supreme Court Justice slot opened in 2024, and US Republicans said "Biden should not appoint Supreme Court Justices in an election year! This was established as the correct rule with the 2016 Merrick Garland nomination at the end of the Obama administration!"

An invalid whataboutism would be "You can't argue with me on this, since you supported the Amy Coney Barret nomination in 2020!"

A valid precedent-cite would be "A more recent precedent is the Amy Coney Barret nomination in 2020. You yourself supported this change in precedence."

**Example 2**

The same approach could be used with the example given in the OP:

- USA: "You invaded Ukraine and killed tens of thousands of people."
- Russia: "Are you arguing that is bad? If so, based on what shared moral rubric?"
- USA: "Yes, it is bad, because it is a UN charter violation."
- Russia: "The precedent that the charter is non-binding, ignorable toilet paper, at least for those nations with veto powers, has already been set when the US started its war on Iraq."

There are moral rubrics that illustrate that this is a *ridiculously unjust war of aggression*, but "UN charter violation" isn't one that really works, given the history.

The US speaker can then respond in a few ways, including:

1. For now, I accept your offered precedent may be valid, for the sake of this argument. I argue instead that your actions in Ukraine are bad because *[alternative moral argument]*.
2. That wasn't a precedent that it was OK to violate the charter, as what we did then was not OK either.
3. That wasn't a precedent that it was OK to violate the charter, as we did not violate it, given *[legal distinction]*, which does not apply in your case.
4. ...and so forth, addressing the precedent cited, rather than being *deflected* into having to defend their own actions.

**What's the difference?**

**Whataboutism** is a *tu coque*/*poisoning-the-well* attack on the actions of the opponent. The goal of this argument is to establish "you have no standing to debate us on this, as you are just as bad" - a fallacy, since speaker-morality does not affect argument-validity.

**Prior precedent** is a citation of historical precedence in defense of the action being discussed. The fact that the precedent was set by the opponent is not used to attack the opponent, but to strengthen the citation: the opponent cannot reasonably argue that they are unaware of, or disagree with the precedent, if they are the ones who set it. The goal of this argument is to establish "we are not in violation of previously-agreed standards."

Comment: Speaker-morality does not affect argument-validity, might be true in the theoretical case. Practically speaking it is very important because often arguments regarding war are highly non verifiable by the broad public, thus a lot of trust is needed in the speaker, thus whataboutism works by casting doubt on the moral integrity of the speaker, thus making those unverifiable arguments less strong or doubtful

Comment: Great answer. *Whataboutism* can be valid in certain political arguments when the other party is knowingly indulging in hypocrisy, and trying to claim a moral high ground,  despite their own history of the same behaviour. In some extremely hypocritical cases, whatsaboutism can even be used to shut down and excuse yourself from a pointless debate - for example, if the Taliban wants to argue women's right with someone from a democratic country where women actually have equal rights.

Comment: You could also cite the willingness of congressional members to support or oppose the filibuster, SCOTUS integrity, and the reach of presidential executive orders as apparently correlated only to which side is the beneficiary as valid whatabout arguments.

Answer (score 6):

> Those who criticize whataboutism, What better type of reply do they suggest?

A more productive, but similar tactic to Whataboutism is using analogous arguments to analyze a given argument.

For instance, someone might argue, "Fireworks should be outlawed, because, when misused, they can cause wildfires." An unhelpful response might be, "Well what about alcohol? When misused, it can cause fatal car accidents. Why don't we outlaw alcohol too?" As established by other answers, this only serves as a distraction from the original argument.

A more helpful response would be, "a similar argument might be made for outlawing alcohol. If you don't support outlawing alcohol, let's consider your reasons for not doing so, and see if any of those reasons might also be a reason for not outlawing fireworks." This opens the door for discussion/debate about the relative merits of each argument, which ideally can clarify whether the argument is valid.

Answer (score 5):

The unspoken part of whataboutism is "therefore you should let me continue what I was doing".

> You're a mass murderer! Killing people is wrong!
>
> Well, you got a speeding ticket. Speeding is wrong. (Therefore you should let me continue to kill people.)

In whataboutism, the criticised party accepts that they're doing something wrong but they deflect attention to the other party. Instead of the criticising party attacking the other party's behaviour, they are now expected to defend their behaviour.

And of course, "two wrongs don't make a right". Sure, maybe the other party is being a hypocrite, but that doesn't mean that their objection is invalid. If both parties are doing something wrong, both should stop. A party should not continue doing bad things because the other party also does or did bad things. If a murderer criticises you for speeding, that criticism is valid despite their own crime.

Comment: but you are also a mass murder, not a person that got a speeding ticket

Comment: "the criticised party accepts that they're doing something wrong". No, they don't.

Answer (score 4):

**Moral Proposition:**
Alice: “I think moral governments do not invade the sovereignty of others, that’s why the recent acts of the Russian government renders it immoral.”

**Whataboutist’s Counter**
Bob: “What about the U.S. government? It’s history of invading the sovereignty of countries like Vietnam, Iraq, and Afghanistan implies that, by your measure, it too lacks morality.”

At this point Alice can:

- Disagree and take the bait — Introduce additional details of varying quality/relevance that render her a hypocrite by her original proposition. “But the U.S. is moral in other ways and many in the world see if as a shining beacon of light on the hill”, to which Bob promptly upbraids her for her naïveté or, at least, makes her eat the can or worms she just opened.
- Revise her opinion — “I hadn’t thought of that counter example, Bob. Upon some reflection, it seems reasonable that I should update my prior belief.” This effectively reveals Alice as having a poorly constructed model of morality (and thus probably not deserving of having her moral statements taken seriously) or having a morality that is easily superseded by other concerns (e.g. acceptance by a group), leading her to being painfully suggestible on issues or morality. Either way, yikes.
- **Agree** — “Yes, and the U.S. government was wrong too, Bob. You’re attempt to excuse the immoral actions of the Russian government by appealing to a low standard (i.e. one historically followed by the U.S. government when it has engaged in similarly immoral behaviors) is *problematic* — if we fail to aspire to a higher moral standard and instead excuse poor behavior because of a relativistic interpretation of morality, then *all bets are off*.

Comment: Indeed, whataboutism is usually dismissed as a logical fallacy, but such a dismissal assumes a formal debate, conducted from the point of view of some universal (or at least established/agreed upon) values. In real life debates this is rarely the case, and *whataboutism* is questioning the moral authority making the judgement... although in practice it is often used to justify A's actions, because B has done so too.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, whataboutism is the logical fallacy [tu quoque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tu_quoque) that literally means 'you too'. It is literally the childish logic that if someone else does something bad, I should be allowed to do something bad too. Many times it is used by dictators, authoritarians (like [Chinese propagandists](https://thediplomat.com/2021/02/responding-to-chinese-whataboutism-on-uyghur-and-native-genocides/) when pressed on Uigyhr concentration camps), and governments that commit crimes against humanity to say if someone else did something bad, I should do bad things too (like when the [Soviet Union](https://www.npr.org/2017/03/17/520435073/trump-embraces-one-of-russias-favorite-propaganda-tactics-whataboutism) would bring up the mistreatment of black people in the United States to deflect issues with their government).  It is not only a bad faith attempt at a logical fallacy disguised as an actual argument and just a way to easily shut up criticism of evil actions, it is literally the kind of logic that would make society collapse if it was applied to a larger scale.  Imagine if someone was allowed to rape and murder as much as they wanted simply because someone in the past or the present got away with it?

Plus, those who fling whataboutisms forget that this logic can work both ways and create a world where leaders try to 'justify' terrible actions by saying other people do bad, so I should do bad. If Putin brings up the bad things America has done when pressed about Ukraine, then American politicians could one day attack a Baltic nation or Middle Eastern country and bring up all the wars [involving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_wars_involving_Russia) Russia, working with the Taliban to put [bounties](https://www.nytimes.com/2020/06/26/us/politics/russia-afghanistan-bounties.html) on US soldier's heads, and the supporting of Islamic [terrorist](https://www.reneweuropegroup.eu/news/2022-11-23/ep-recognises-russia-as-state-sponsoring-terrorism-and-using-terrorist-means) groups as well all Soviet war crimes in a similar whataboutism conversation. Basically, now even US politicians and others have an excuse to not try to be better and instead claim that if anyone who calls them out has ever done anything bad, then any terrible actions they do are now justified.

Whataboutism also often uses [false equivalency](https://effectiviology.com/false-equivalence/) by comparing two things with different contexts to try to justify a bad action.  Imagine if someone tried to get away with murder by claiming that someone who killed a person in self-defense got to kill someone, so they get to kill someone?  This line of reasoning completely ignores the context of why one action is considered justified and the other isn't: the fact that 1 person took a life to defend their own and the other takes a life because they simply felt like it. You could have one person say they should be allowed to speed because ambulance drivers speed, but that ignores that one person speeds simply because they want to and the other speeds to try to save a life!

Answer (score 2):

"Whataboutism" is often criticized, but usually by the people who made the original comment that someone has replied to with a Whatabout.

The Whataboutists may well feel that the Original Commenters have somehow grabbed the attention of the audience by unfair means and they are upset that the OC's points are getting more attention than similar comments that they may have tried to make about other issues that they consider equally or more grave. E.g.

"It's outrageous that people are damaging art works as a protest."
"But it's even worse that people are pointing at that, when Climate Change is causing an Emergency, and they are ignoring that."

Comment: Just because something else is wrong doesn't make a wrong doing by you right. In your example damaging fancy works of art does nothing to address the issues and causes of climate change.

Comment: Your example doesn't work in practice. Even those that agree it's now a climate "emergency" are upset about defaced art. This is an example of an invalid whatabout, because it assumes mutually exclusive opinions.

Answer (score 1):

The examples listed as "what about" are often large, complex cases on they own, each deserving separate question, answer, source and discussions. When listed as "what about", it is usually in comments, without sources, without context and often even without enough information that would help finding these sources independently. "What about [USA invading Kuwait in 1990](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gulf_War)?" Looks like just sit and decided to invade Kuwait at that year, likely with no reasons at all and simply having nothing else to do. The lazy reader is pressed to accept the claims on belief because it seems way too much work to verify them.

Due what, whataboutism is most often seen (and is) a propaganda technique. And this is not counting that it is also logical fallacy even when listed cases are relevant, as already well addressed in other answers.

Comment: Confronting an opponent with a slew of difficult to answer questions rather than a reasoned reply is called a gish gallop. Not a fallacy, but certainly dishonest, since the point is to overwhelm and silence your opponent.

Answer (score 0):

It's fairly obvious that this question is not a genuine attempt to ask about "whataboutism," but to sneak in the actual bona fide fallacy of false-equivalence under the guise of using a "whataboutism."

Nevertheless, it still ends up asking a relevant question.

---

"Whataboutism" is not evil.  Nor is it even wrong.  It's a [dysphemism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysphemism) used to excuse hypocrisy.

More specifically, it's a word used to vilify arguments which point out hypocrisies.  Rather than addressing the hypocrisy by, at the very least acknowledging that a **multifaceted argument can have components which are present in arguments on the other side**, a dysphemism is used to dismiss a perfectly valid concern.

It usually goes something like this (capital letters are principles states in arguments for the sake of this example):

pro:
A & B ==> X

is followed by a counter

con:
C & B ==> not X

pro(vilification):
"nice whataboutism! you are refusing to address B!"

con:
"well, no, I am pointing out the hypocrisy that B can also be a component of 'not X."

The dysphemism is used to create a he-said-she-said-type situation in order to divert attention from the hypocrisy.

This is effective because hypocrisies cause [moral panics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moral_panic).  But using vilification terms also cause moral panics.

And when people do not analyze argument coolly, but only pay attention at a superficial level, the two counteracting moral panics provide 2 opposing incentives, thereby weakening the impetus produced by the initial accusation of hypocrisy.

---

## But,

it is probably important to mention that while "whataboutism" is a false "logical fallacy," there is a closely-related logical fallacy, which is real.  And that is a "[false equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_equivalence)."

And, in fact, **the OP question is a good example of a false equivalence**.  False equivalence is comparing things which have common elements and uncommon elements, but ignoring the uncommon elements while insisting that the common elements are the only ones which are present.

It goes something like this:

pro:

A & B (without mentioning C which is true and relevant) ==> X

A & B (without mentioning C which is NOT true and which is still relevant) ==> Y

con:

whether or not C happened is extremely relevant here.  It was present in X, so X is true. It was absent in Y, so Y is false.

Of course, there is obviously a very large difference between the military actions taken during wars by the United States and the unprovoked war of aggression, being waged by Russia against Ukraine with the [stated purpose of committing genocide](https://twitter.com/TimothyDSnyder/status/1512450303571992579) of Ukraine.

Comment: Confusing. I think most people accept that whataboutism is an attempt to expose alleged hypocracy, rather than to excuse it.

Comment: @reallydismayed but the accusation of "whataboutism" can be an attempt to excuse a hypocrisy.  I do agree that the way I wrote this up can be confusing.  I thought about rewriting it a few times, but couldn't think of a more cogent way to phrase it.

Comment: I think it's most relevant the way you say it, since in my experience, most charges of whataboutism are invalid and intended to excuse hypocrisy. The whatabout itself often goes unanswered, since apparently "whataboutism" is a magic word.

Answer (score -4):

I guess it is particulary **just**, because it exposes double standards. Say, a girl says - I like guys with long beard (Stmt1). Whataboutism approach is - " But your friend is without a beard". This may point to the falcity of Stmt1.

The **right** answers in difference between USA and Russia, is for example - "Russia, what type of power do you export in the regions, assume you have conquered it? Will you export corrupt oligarch dictature in those territories?"
This clarifies the sides

Comment: That's a horrible example; I like cats doesn't mean I don't like dogs, and if someone sexually attracted to guys says "I like guys with long beards", in English, that generally doesn't mean anything about who they want to be friends with. Even if this were fixed, if she said "I only date guys with long beards" and you pointed out her boyfriend didn't have a beard, it wouldn't be "whataboutism"; it would simply be a counterexample.

Comment: Your example isn't relevant at all and is completely wrong. Stating you like guys with long beards does not imply anything at all about guys without a long beard or a beard at all. In fact it doesn't even imply that you like all guys with a long beard and can't dislike a guy with a long beard.

Comment: @prosfilaes ok, i will try to improve example. Assuming a girl is dating the guy with the beard. The says " it is because i like guys only with beards". But you know, that former boyfriend of her was without a beard. this is so called "double standarts", what show, that she is dishonest or there are further factors what she concideres

Comment: @user184868 That's still not double standards or whataboutism.